# How to set properties of usercontrol from markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I cannot find an answer for this simple question anywhere.
So, let's say I have MyUserControl that has a public property like this:

```
    public int myInt
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)ViewState[MyKey];
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState[MyKey] = value;
            }
        }
```

What I can do is I can drop this control on the page and the set this proeprty on page_load like this:

```
controlId.myInt =10;
```

But how can I do the same in markup with (possibly) an intelliscense.  something like this:

```
<myNamesplace:MyUserControl Id="controlId" runat="server" myInt="10" />
```

Comment: This code of yours should work.

Comment: I'm with @tucaz, the code provided should work without issues.

Comment: @tucaz, But intellisense doesn't have those properties listed, also, I'd like to have a lsit of available values to popup.

Comment: Having intellisense and making it work are two different things. If you want intellisense check @malkassem reply

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register your assembly that contains the control on the page first:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="your.assembly" Namespace="your.namespace" TagPrefix="myNamespace" %>
```

Then intelliscense should pick it up.

Comment: No it doesn't work to some reason even if register it like you show. I register it through src="mypathtocontrol"